# Github undoing merge

Tags: git, github

I don't know what happened but for some reason when I try to use github again I get this error saying that I'm trying to merge something. I completely want to undo the whole thing:

```
E325: ATTENTION
Found a swap file by the name ".git/.MERGE_MSG.swp"
      owned by: mauriciosanchezduque   dated: Tue May 21 22:18:59 2013
     file name: ~mauriciosanchezduque/.git/MERGE_MSG
      modified: YES
     user name: mauriciosanchezduque   host name: Mauricios-MacBook-Pro.local
    process ID: 4738
While opening file ".git/MERGE_MSG"
         dated: Tue May 21 22:27:11 2013
  NEWER than swap file!
```

I was just trying to pull a new repository and insert some files to start working on it but terminal came up with this message. Any suggestions?

I did a **git stash** and it seemed to work! But I think I completely messed up github because when I was able to pull the repository I was trying to use it put it on the user folder. So I think git was trying to push all my computer to github. I think at certain point I did a git push -A in the wrong folder and pushed a bunch of folders and files. when I do a git status it shows a bunch of untracked stuff that is in my computer as well as deleted folders. Any idea of how to take it from here? this is what I get:

```
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#   .Trash/
#   .dropbox/
#   .openmdao/
#   Documents/Arduino/
#   Documents/OpenMDAO/
#   Documents/gitHub/
#   Documents/mySite/
#   Documents/openFrameworks/
#   Dropbox/
#   Library/
#   Music/
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To abort screwed up merge, you need to use rather unintuitive

```
git reset --merge
```

Most other commands like `git rebase`, `git am` use `--abort` switch for this which is much easier to remember. But, `git merge` somehow does not support `--abort`.

Comment: `git merge` does have a `--abort`.

Comment: Well, it did support it until version 1.7.4. Note from release notes for 1.7.4:  "git merge" learned the "--abort" option, synonymous to    "git reset --merge" when a merge is in progress.

Answer (score 2):

This is your text editor, vim, complaining, not git.  It's indicating you have the `MERGE_MSG` file open somewhere else.  Likely you tried to pull, left an editor open and then tried to pull again.

You can probably safely close the other editor or delete the `.MERGE_MSG.swp` file before you try again.  Though if you're pulling new history into the repository you may wish to [rebase](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rebase.html).  (You can do `git pull --rebase` to fetch and rebase instead of fetch and merge.)

A simpler option though, if you're just trying to get a brand new repository and don't have any local edits, is to re-clone it from GitHub.

Answer (score 1):

For those that got the same error on a `git merge`and came here (as I did):

All I had to do to get around this error was to add a `-m "Commit message"` to the line.

`git merge <branchname> -m "Commit message"`